# Wordpress - Customizing href of tag cloud entries

Tags: wordpress, tag-cloud

I've got the standard tag cloud in my sidebar.

However, I've written my theme from scratch, and it operates a bit differently. Instead of the hrefs for each tag in my cloud leading to `mysite.com/tag1` I need it to be run through my internal search engine, so the href should look like `mysite.com/?s=tag1&submit=Search`.

Is there an easier way to do this (maybe adding a function to `functions.php`), than by writing my own tag cloud plug-in from scratch?

Comment: Maybe a bit off-topic, but be careful you're not killing your SEO with such customizations.

Comment: How does customizing my theme like this kill SEO?

Comment: I don't say it does, but it could. You're running your tags (which are great for SEO) through a search engine with parameters (less good for SEO) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the filter [widget_tag_cloud_args](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/widget_tag_cloud_args) not sure if it works.
You also could extend the class `WP_Widget_Tag_Cloud`